# Unable to convert a particular string format to DateTime

Tags: apex, datetime, string

I have the following dateTime values

2023-11-05 09:16:14
2023-11-07 09:16:14

Im getting them properly from a table using Apex code

```
DateTime startDt = informaticaAuditTableRecords[0].startDate;
DateTime endDt= informaticaAuditTableRecords[0].EndDate
```

I have now converted them into a particular string format below using this snippet

```
String d1;
String d2;

d1 = startDt.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
d2 = endDt.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
```

Problem is when Im trying to convert this String back to the DateTime Format using below Snippet

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.valueOfGmt(d1);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.valueOfGmt(d2);
```

I am getting the below error
System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2023-11-05T09:16:14Z

I am unable to parse this string properly to Date Time
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `(Datetime) JSON.deserialize('"' + d1 + '"', Datetime.class)`? JSON expects date/time values to be in UTC anyway so I *think* this should work...

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

()..

```
DateTime dt1 = Datetime.valueOf(d1.replace('T',' '));
DateTime dt1 = Datetime.valueOf(d2.replace('T',' '));
```

Comment: I think this will struggle with the time zone aspect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON to correctly parse the values back into DateTime values.

```
DateTime dt1 = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"'+d1+'"', DateTime.class);
DateTime dt2 = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"'+d2+'"', DateTime.class);
```

Comment: As per my comment, indeed. Note that according to the tooling API the class name is `Datetime` rather than `DateTime` (not that this impacts the code, of course).

Comment: @PhilW So you did. I guess that's what I get for skipping comments (and you for not posting as an answer, lol). Tangentially, I'm curious why you comment more than you answer? There's so many times when I go "huh, I wonder why Phil, who's almost always right, doesn't answer as many questions as they could?"

Comment: It generally comes down to: 1. Only being on a mobile and not wanting to do a lot of typing since the experience is painful and 2. where I do not have time to double-check what I am saying (so not 100% sure the answer is correct), but 3. I feel I have something to contribute.

Comment: @PhilW Like I said, was just curious. We all contribute in our own ways, like those who just edit, those to clean the queues religiously, etc. As long as you're happy, that's the only thing that matters.